# Need a powerful spell checker for French please

Tags: spell-checker, french

Since 1999 we are using the commercial spell checker Cordial from Synapse. Sadly, the language-competence of Cordial is slowly getting better, but the installation and integration into our Windows and our Office tools is getting worse. The latest version Cordial 22 does not even install any longer on my Windows 10 pro 64bit. I am working with their support, but since the trend is clear and the installation is not working, we need to move on.

Our computers are Windows 10 pro but our set-up is NOT French, and - because of work reasons - we do not run the latest MS Office, but some very recent LibreOffice version. The GUI of those are also NOT in French, which might be a reason for the installation-issues of Cordial, but is not negotiable.

We are ready to spend money. And we do not mind using OpenSource if the results are good.

We do not need much integration; a well working stand-along spell checker would be fine - as long as copy&paste or basic file-opening/save-as etc. is available.

We need powerful analysis of real and complex French texts, including publications for West Africa and reports for governments, sponsors so that the marked "errors" and the proposed "corrections" will be appropriate. Nobody in our team is a mother-tongue speaker of French. We try to write mostly French French, with only a few African expressions included.

French has got some "special" typographic rules. And lots of traps concerning accord within a sentence or text. For example, when a text is saying "we" (nous) and is written by several females only, then a spell checker should be aware of that and work accordingly, i.e. there needs to be an option to enter such detail.

So our main challenge is not from typos, or from OCR but from authors who in theory know most of the French spelling rules, but are often missing some details.

We own good dictionaries already, so no need to have them integrated in a spell checker solution. But no harm if they come included in some reasonable package.

I will look into Grammalecte soon.

We have looked into ProLexis in 2017 but had some ghastly security warnings triggered from their server (while trying to install a trial version) and the sales team was not helpful (considering the impressive list price).

I have had a read through this website:  https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/articles/correcteur-orthographe/

Now I would like to hear, what my Stackexchange community can add from real-life experience, please. I can myself google all the tools that are out there; I would love to hear from actual users with mildly similar context. Thank you.